# Is there functionality built into ros to get nodes to print a stacktrace on crash?

Tags: ros, gdb, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When ROS nodes crash, modifying launch files to run under gdb is often required to get a stack trace. And a full reattempt to produce the conditions of the crash is necessary.

75% of crash failures (made up number :) could probably be solved without running in the debugger if we could see where the crash happened on each failure.

Is there functionality built into ROS to handle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9943/is-there-functionality-built-into-ros-to-get-nodes-to-print-a-stacktrace-on-crash?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option (which has nothing to do with ROS internals) is to set the ulimit on core file to be non-zero and then analyze the core after the crash. (By default the core size limit is set to 0 in Ubuntu)

Set to unlimited:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

This will cause the OS to produce a "core file" each time there is a crash which contains some of the info needed to recreate a stack trace. The other portion of the info is contained in the executable which crashed.

The core file ends up in  `~/.ros` and can be analyzed with gdb like so:

```
gdb --core=~/.ros/core  /path/to/stack/package/bin/mynode
```

... where a backtrace can be obtained by using the "`backtrace`" or "`bt`" command

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dg-shadow](https://answers.ros.org/users/30495/dg-shadow/) on 2017-05-23**:
Has anyone had any luck doing this? The core file doesn't seem to turn up in ~/.ros for me...

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2017-10-04**:
Had the same problem as you, ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. Tried the /proc/sys... stuff here as well: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

**Comment by [Beshari](https://answers.ros.org/users/38636/beshari/) on 2022-08-25**:
I was able to follow this, my core dump was in /var/crash, and you can find the executable of a package folder using
`pkgname=<your package name>`

`catkin_find --first-only --without-underlays --libexec ${pkgname}`

then after starting gdb with the top command, you can type `bt`, or `where`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not.   You could ticket this as an enhancement...

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1